# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am facing this converting failed. I want to get all the selected date in calender and show event on the selected date. I able to get selected date but when I try to get start day = to selected date. It failed with error below.

> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
   strSQL = " SELECT CalendarID, Company,Header, convert(date,enddate,103)StartDate, convert(varchar,enddate,103) enddate, (starthour + ' : ' + startmin + ' : ' + startday) starttime,  (endhour  + ' : '+ endmin+ ' : '+ endday) endtime " & _
                  "FROM tablename where StartDate ='" & calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString() & "'"
```

I have try to change the codes into this but also having the same error

```
Dim selecteddates As Date
        selecteddates = calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()

 strSQL = " SELECT CalendarID, Company,Header, convert(date,enddate,103)StartDate, convert(date,enddate,103) enddate, (starthour + ' : ' + startmin + ' : ' + startday) starttime,  (endhour  + ' : '+ endmin+ ' : '+ endday) endtime " & _
                  "FROM tablename where StartDate =CAST('" & selecteddates & "' AS DATE) "
```

Comment: This is a bad way of coding. Don't do concatenation in sql queries. It is vulnerable . I suggest you to use parametrised queries

Comment: To add to what Sankar is saying, by switching to using parameters, you also benefit here because ADO.Net already knows how to translate .NET's `DateTime` into SQL Server's `datetime` (or `datetime2`, etc) data types, so you don't have to render the date as a *string* at all, and so you eliminate your formatting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer(s) is already given in the comments. I am just adding sample code here to make it more clear:

```
Dim strSQL As String  = <sql>SELECT CalendarID, Company,Header, 
           convert(date,enddate,103) StartDate, convert(varchar,enddate,103) enddate, 
           (starthour + ' : ' + startmin + ' : ' + startday) starttime,  
           (endhour  + ' : '+ endmin+ ' : '+ endday) endtime
           FROM mytablename 
           where StartDate >= @dtStart and StartDate < @dtEnd
           </sql>

Dim tbl As New DataTable()
Using con As New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLExpress;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes")
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = calendar1.SelectedDate.Date
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(1)
        con.Open()
        tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```